# How to create an obfuscated apk in android by using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm new to using proguard.
I want to create an obfuscated apk by using proguard.
I created a signed apk after uncommenting

```
proguard.config = ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

The apk I'm getting is not obfuscated.
If I reverse engineer the APK by using `dex2jar`, I'm getting the class files and they're not obfuscated.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is not obfuscated? the complete class or the strings constants?

Comment: @vzamanillo all the xml files. I saved api details and credentials in strings.xml. these are all not obfuscated and how can i prevent it?

Comment: Show us your proguard config file contents, please.

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard only obfuscates and optimizes bytecode. You should see renamed classes, fields, and methods. ProGuard's commercial, Android-specific sibling DexGuard provides additional application protection techniques, such as string encryption and asset encryption, although not encryption of strings in resource XML files, at this time.

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)